# Emacs CEDET EDE non-trivial project setups

Tags: emacs, cedet

Trying to understand how EDE works by using it to generate Makefiles for
a project directory that contains several targets under a specific
hierarchy.  I'm not having any luck, and the info pages don't seem to
answer my question.

My directory structure looks something like:
(The asterix (*) marks files containing main() functions)

```
research/
  flow/
    flow.cpp
    flow.hpp
    program.cpp *

  samples/
    sample1.yuv

  utils/
    yuvreader.cpp
    yuvreader.hpp

  tests/
    yuvreader_test.cpp *
```

I want to create EDE project(s) with one or more subprojects; or maybe I
just want one or more targets...?

flow's program.cpp requires flow/ and utils/ sources, but yuvreader_test
only requires utils/ sources.

I did ede-new in the root directory, and all subdirectories.  I also did ede-new-target in the root directory, but when adding source files in subdirectories, it does not recognize the target I created.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to some more complicated
Project.ede files for something like I'm trying to do.  You can guess
that I have more subdirectories containing class code files, some of
which have standalone programs that use that code; also I have more test
code under tests/.  Any example files/command workflows would be
appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EDE feature that will generate Makefile or Automakefiles has a few more constraints than either Make or Automake.  For example, the files belonging to a target must be in the same directory as the project containing the target.  In  your example, you would probably have no projects in your root directory.

To bring multiple sources together into a single program, a simple mechanism is to have each subdirectory create an archive (.a) or a shared lib (.so) that is linked together in your program.

If that is too constraining, you can also write your own automake files, and EDE will read those directly, so you can have a more complex build procedure as needed.

The CEDET distribution uses EDE as its build process, so you could look at that as a complex example.  It doesn't build C++ files though, so it may not be as helpful as you would like.

Comment: Sadly, I expected this to be the case.  Thanks for the explanation; though I am reluctant, I'll accept this as an answer.  I would like to see the type of top-level structure implemented into EDE in the future - saving me time from writing CMakeLists or automake files, etc.

Comment: Due to a recent influx of similar EDE project questions, I created a Quick Start section in the manual that describes a basic project that has an include directory and shared libraries.  The auto-built version is here: http://www.randomsample.de/cedetdocs/ede/ede/Quick-Start.html